# Why is my provider asking me to use a VLAN

Tags: vlan, wide-area-network

We are getting a fiber PTP circuit from Verizon, and have been having trouble going live with it. Finally, through a conference call with Verizon, they tell us to configure point A as VLAN 29 and point B as VLAN 45. After doing so, we are able to establish communications. We told them to remove the VLAN because we should not need it on a point to point connection, which resulted in a change order that will take a month to complete. The reason I ask is because getting this connection has taken over a year, and Verizon says that we requested the VLAN. They also say that it is more secure. Is this some kind of industry standard that I don't know about?

Comment: I've never heard of "vlans are security" but then again there are people that think NAT adds security, so perhaps its something ridiculous like that.

Answer (score 2):

One aspect of security with VLANs that Verizon may be (but I doubt it) thinking of, is that they allow/cause you to separate your network into logical (virtual) segments. If you have hosts on VLAN 29 and other hosts on VLAN 45, then those networks cannot talk to each other without being routed, so the traffic will be localized to that particular VLAN. This could be considered "more secure" (not "secure") because traffic between VLANs can be regulated, controlled, stopped with firewalls, etc.

I'd be more inclined to think that some Verizon person has no idea what they're talking about and just regurgitated something they heard somewhere else, but that's just my experience with them as well. At a previous job, we worked with them to get dark fiber and other connections run between my company's locations, and it was like explaining quantum mechanics to my child. Blank stares and crickets.

Answer (score 1):

A VLAN will allow you to use a single physical Ethernet link between two locations to carry traffic of multiple logically separate Ethernet segments.

For example suppose at location A you have hosts A1 and A2 and at location B you have hosts B1 and B2. You have a single Ethernet cable between the two locations through which A1 will need to communicate with B1, and A2 will need to communicate with B2. No other communication is permitted.

You could attach an unmanaged switch to each end of the connection and configure A1 and B1 with one IP prefix and A2 and B2 with another IP prefix. However this is not highly secure as all hosts can still communicate with each other if only they do so using IP addresses from the other prefix than they were supposed to.

In such a setup using VLAN tagging can improve security. Instead of an unmanaged switch at each end a managed switch can be used. They can be configured to use VLAN tagging on the link between the two locations such that the traffic can be kept separate.

Then it will no longer be possible for A1 to communicate with any host other than B1, etc.

Whether such security needs apply to your scenario is impossible to say given the limited details in your question. If you do not have any need for the isolation provided by VLAN tagging, then there is no security to be gained from enabling VLAN tagging.

Comment: I have no use for VLAN tagging right now, I want a connection from point A to point B with all hosts being able to communicate. It is the telco that was requiring the use of VLAN's, which made no sense to me. My understanding is that they can use whatever routing or segmenting or tagging that they want inside of their network, and I should never know the difference. I should be able to see the WAN IP addresses at point A and point B, and set up a route between the two that allows my LAN's to see each other.